# Bash script, stopping a process running forever when a line is printed

Tags: bash, process

I'm new in scripting in Bash; what I want to do is running a process that runs forever (i.e. Gulp) and stops it when it prints to screen a line.

In my case, when I start Gulp it prints thousands of lines (it takes about 20 seconds), then it remains in waiting; the last line it prints is always

```
[Browsersync] Serving files from: src
```

I tried to reach my aim with this script:

```
cd ~/mydir
gulp serve &
while read -r line; do
    if [ "$line"=="[Browsersync] Serving files from: src" ]; then
    echo 'pid of Gulp before killing it is : ' `pidof gulp`
    # Get its PID
    PID=$!
    kill -INT $PID
    echo 'pid of Gulp now is : ' `pidof gulp`
    fi
done
```

But this doesn't stop gulp process. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: note that this is just a slice of the entire script.

Comment: it doesnt work with if [ "$line"="[Browsersync] Serving files from: src" ];
and if [ "$line" = "[Browsersync] Serving files from: src" ]; 
either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect the output of your background-running program with `read`'s input.

The easiest way to do it is to run it as a `bash` [`coprocess`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Coprocesses):

> A coprocess is executed asynchronously in a subshell, as if the command had been terminated with the `&` control operator, **with a two-way pipe established between the executing shell and the coprocess**.

The standard output of your command (`gulp serve`) will be available in a file descriptor in `COPROC[0]` (first element of `COPROC` array), and the PID in `COPROC_PID`.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
coproc gulp serve
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [ "$line" == "[Browsersync] Serving files from: src" ]; then
        kill -INT "$COPROC_PID"
    fi
done <&"${COPROC[0]}"
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I think gulp serve is stopped as soon as it is started, because it does not print their lines on screen; or is it a normal behaviour?

Comment: See the output from gulp by adding echo "$line" between while and if. Maybe it exits normally without printing anything.

Comment: you were right! Gulp output is exactly what expected, thanks so much for your help!